# How to split python dataframe data while exporting to csv files

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have dataframe with 1 Million rows, I want to export to 2 csv files - 500k each.

Below code I use to export to csv:

```
exportPath='C:\sunil_plus\dataset\Data2SQLImport\reults.csv'
header=['Country','Indicator','Measure','Unit','Frequency','Date','Value']
data.to_csv(exportPath,columns=header,sep=',',index=False))
```

Comment: @EdChum, while exporting I want to write to multiple csv files as per total count mentioned. In this case I want to export 5L rows to 2 csv file

Comment: The dupe shows how to slice a df into different chunks you need to take a slice of the df and then export

Comment: @EdChum, thanks... working...

Comment: @EdChum, if I have to split more than 3/or more dataframe then how to do that:

    if data.shape[0] > 500000:
        exportFile1 = data[:500000]
        exportFile2 = data[500000:]

Comment: You can just divide the number of rows to n or more dfs, this is really simple arithmetic

Comment: yes I got it, thanks

exportFile1 = data[:500000] 
exportFile2 = data[500000:1000000]
exportFile3 = data[1000000:]